# How imported class work in Groovy Closure when calling it?

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy Closure which uses some imported class like:

```
import com.XXX

Closure test = { a -> XXX(a) }

test('some str')
```

How the imported class XXX work inside closure test since I never defined the XXX in test.
In this case delegate and owner are point to current script and still not figure out how import work.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got an example that can be executed?

Comment: Is this about how the "import" ends up in the generated inner class?

Answer (score 0):

This example works, maybe look at how you specify the import statement's package structure:

```
assert org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils.capitalizeFully('groovy closure') == 'Groovy Closure'

import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils
Closure test = { a -> WordUtils.capitalizeFully(a) }
assert test('groovy closure') == 'Groovy Closure'
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out this is a Java related question.

"import" key word in Java is kind of a syntax sugar which let you claim a class without full path name. And when the class file be compiled, class name will be replaced by full path of import by compiler.

So in my case, XXX will be compiled to com.XXX inside Closure(does not matter it is a Java or Groovy class), and it will work in any class which been called.